# Eliminar múltiples archivos del servidor

Tags: laravel, imagen

Estoy trabajando con imágenes en Laravel y resulta que quiero eliminar todas las imágenes que pertenecen a un objeto con un método, mi código en el controlador está así:

```
public function purge($id)
  {
    $objeto   = Objeto::find($id);
    $photos   = Gallery::where('obj_id',$objeto->id);

    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
      if (file_exists(public_path('galeria/'.$photo->file))) {
        unlink(public_path('galeria/'.$photo->file));
      }
      $photo->delete();
    }

    return back();
  }
```

O sea, que mi modelo Gallery contiene las imágenes que pertenecen a Objeto.

Gracias de antemano, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener las photos a través de una relación con el objeto de manera mas comoda, pero bueno el problema segun yo es porque te falta obtener la colección

```
$photos   = Gallery::where('obj_id',$objeto->id)->get();
```

Mientras no uses "get" seguiras trabajando en la query, y con el "get" en los resultados de la query

Comment: Mil gracias, con eso anduvo perfecto!